# Treeview and list view control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have following sample `xml` file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>

   <IResponse   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLScheminstance"                            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <Language>en</Language>
   <Code>Approved</Code>
   <Message> Approved</Message>
   <Info xsi:type="Info">
   <Number>11</Number>
   <ExpiryDate year="10" month="8" />
   <StartDate year="7" month="8" />
   <currency="GBP">36.00</currency>

  <ACode>096392</ACode>
  </IResponse>
```

How to display the nodes and child elemants in `treeview` control and values in the `list view`?

```
     public void Deserialize()
    {
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(this.filePath);
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response));
        if (serializer.CanDeserialize(reader))
        {
            Response obj = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as Response;

          // obj consists of xml file nodes and i want to display this in treeview
            // control and values in between them as list view .
        }
        else
        {
            iccTransactionResponseBindingSource.DataSource = null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Down voter please comment ...

Comment: Wwhat seems the be problem? Parsing the XML or adding nodes to a TreeView ?

Comment: I am done with parsing xml i never used tree view control so just wondering how to add nodes to the treeview

Comment: Which UI framework are you asking about? WinForms? WPF? ASP.NET? Silverlight? LightSwitch?

Comment: Added the WinForms tag for you.

Comment: Please show your code and ask specific questions about where you're stuck.

Comment: @Terry Donaghe : see my edited post

Comment: The choice of controls is odd, neither are very good at displaying xml.  Just use a WebBrowser so you don't have to write any code.

Comment: @Hans Passant : can you tel me how to use webbrowser

Comment: I think Hans is implying to just open the XML file in a web browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this MS KB document? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317597